# How can I implement toggling based on data received from endpoint?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement the same like/dislike functionality as Instagram on the frontend.

The `setGridData` hook is grabbing the correct values from the server and `handleDislike()` and `handleLike()` are correctly updating the DB table for the currently logged in user so no issues there.

The problem I'm having is implementing a way the currently logged in user will hit the `if` (dislike) block or the `else` (like)  block in `handleLikesBasedOnUserId()` based on the `is_liked` boolean value.

In the JSX, I'm correctly displaying `Like`  or `Dislike` on the button based on the `is_liked` boolean value that's coming from the `gridData` hook for the currently logged in user.  However, when clicking the button, it's always hitting the `else` (like) block in `handleLikesBasedOnUserId()` no matter what.

How can I fix it so that it behaves exactly the same as Instagram?

Here's the code:

```
const Grid = () => {
let authToken                                                 = localStorage.getItem('token');

const [gridData, setGridData]                                 = useState([]);
const [userLikedPhotos, setUserLikedPhotos]                   = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    const headers = {
        "Accept": 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
    };

    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-user-uploads-data', {headers})
        .then(resp => {
            console.log(resp.data);
            setGridData(resp.data);
        }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

}, []);

const handleLikesBasedOnUserId = (likedPhotoUserId, userName, likedPhotoId, is_liked) => {
    if(userLikedPhotos[likedPhotoUserId]) {
        // dislike
        delete userLikedPhotos[likedPhotoUserId];
        gridData.find(photo => photo.UserID === likedPhotoUserId && photo.is_liked === is_liked && photo.photo_id === likedPhotoId).likes--;
        handleDislike(likedPhotoUserId, userName, likedPhotoId);

        console.log("Disliked");
    } else {
        // like
        userLikedPhotos[likedPhotoUserId] = true;
        gridData.find(photo => photo.UserID === likedPhotoUserId && photo.is_liked === is_liked && photo.photo_id === likedPhotoId).likes++;
        handleLike(likedPhotoUserId, userName, likedPhotoId);

        console.log("Liked");
    }

    setUserLikedPhotos({...userLikedPhotos});
};

return (
    <>
        <div className="img-container">
            {
                gridData.map((photos, index) => {
                    return (
                        <>
                            <div className="userDetails">
                                <span className="likesAmt">❤️ {photos.likes}</span>
                                <Button 
                                    variant={photos.is_liked ? `danger` : 'success'} 
                                    onClick={() => handleLikesBasedOnUserId(photos.UserID, photos.name, photos.photo_id, photos.is_liked)}
                                >
                                    {photos.is_liked ? `Dislike` : 'Like'}
                                </Button>
                            </div>
                        </>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>                
    </>
  )
}

export default Grid;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not modify state variable. Instead copy it first, then modify the copy:

   ```
   const handleLikesBasedOnUserId = (likedPhotoUserId, userName, likedPhotoId, is_liked) => {
    const temp = {...userLikedPhotos};
    if(temp[likedPhotoUserId]) {
        // dislike
        delete temp[likedPhotoUserId];
        gridData.find(photo => photo.UserID === likedPhotoUserId && photo.is_liked === is_liked && photo.photo_id === likedPhotoId).likes--;
        handleDislike(likedPhotoUserId, userName, likedPhotoId);

        console.log("Disliked");
    } else {
        // like
        temp[likedPhotoUserId] = true;
        gridData.find(photo => photo.UserID === likedPhotoUserId && photo.is_liked === is_liked && photo.photo_id === likedPhotoId).likes++;
        handleLike(likedPhotoUserId, userName, likedPhotoId);

        console.log("Liked");
    }

    setUserLikedPhotos(temp);
   };
   ```
2. Don't you need to initialize `userLikedPhotos` to the `id`s of the photos having `photos.is_liked === true` at the beginning?
3. Why do you need `userLikedPhotos` anyway? Why not just use `photo.is_liked`?

Answer (score -1):

The moment you set state for setUserLikedPhotos, your component re-renders and it sets your state to default. Please try to use useRef().

```
let existingLikedPhotos = useRef({});
const [userLikedPhotos, setUserLikedPhotos] = useState(existingLikedPhotos.current);
.
.
.
existingLikedPhotos.current = {...userLikedPhotos};
setUserLikedPhotos({...userLikedPhotos});
```

Make the changes as suggested. Then from next time it rerenders it will have your changes from previous rerenders in useRef variable.

Comment: I've already tried that, it still doesn't work.

Comment: The current behavior right now is that it likes/dislikes each photo correctly but the state isn't maintained, in other words, when you refresh the page, you can like the same photo multiple times

Comment: Please check the edited answer above. I believe the component rerenders and it reset your state.

Comment: I don't think `useRef()` is appropriate to use in this case in terms of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: I have added the code above. Please check it.

Comment: Ok I'll try it.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Try consoling and see where things going wrong.

Comment: Make sure you passed likedPhotoId instead of likedPhotoUserId at both places.